# portable air conditioner exhaust

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a problem similar to this:

[How can I vent a portable air conditioner when there's no window?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62136/how-can-i-vent-a-portable-air-conditioner-when-theres-no-window)

I do have windows but I cannot modify them. Cutting holes in walls or any similar modifications are not allowed.

I was thinking about using a stove hood to release the hot air. Will it be a good solution?

[image: http://ak1.ostkcdn.com/img/mxc/100107_range-hood.jpg]

Comment: Are you sure that the vent hood even goes outside?  In many installations, it just blows the air back into the room...

Comment: That's interesting. I had had a lifelong experience with a hood that goes into a ventilation system so I haven't even thought it could be any different. What is the point of having it just circulating the air? To prevent fungi from growing? Anyway, the one I have here indeed does not go outside. Oh dear...

Comment: I have no idea what the point is of even having a non-vented vent-hood, but it's shockingly common in apartments and cheaply built homes.

Comment: It's supposed to have a filter on it to remove smells/smoke. Still a bit useless, of course.

Comment: The filters supposedly collect grease - they collect very little, and have no impact on smoke/smells. They are cheap products installed by cheap builders and cheap landlords which are basically useless.

Comment: @stoveproblem If one ventilation canal is shared among more than 1 inlet, then it's **strictly forbidden** to forcefully blow air into it. Because it will make it come out through other inlets, effectively removing ventilation from that rooms. Only natural updraft is allowed in shared canals.
Most customer-oriented hoods have filters anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

??? Venting a portable A/C does not require "modifying" the window at all. You open the window, insert the exhaust-hose plate, close the window onto it, perhaps stuff some foam between the upper and lower pane, and you're done, without modifications to the window...

Comment: I want to avoid opening the window due to significant number of insects around. Also it's outward opening so using insect nets is somewhat problematic. Nevertheless this or a similar solution seems to be the only option at this point.

Answer (score 0):

In essence you could use duct to vent the hot air going out, but you should attach it to the AC for best results. You need cool air supplied to the sides of the AC which absorb the heat and transfer it away.

[image]

Would a cassette AC work? I think it would work for the thread "How can I vent a portable air conditioner when there's no window?", but that wasn't really the question here nor there; but I truly think it's the solution that both of you are looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They make air conditioning units with exhaust pipes for either the hot or the cold air.  I once had a server room whose door was propped open 6” specifically to allow such a unit to blow air in there. Wasn't my design.